# How to get the actual file object from Camel FTP route exchange

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

In my Camel router:

```
from(<SourceURI>)
.process(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        // I want to extract the file object from the exchange
    }
.to(<targetURI>).
```

How can I achieve this?

I tried e.g. `exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, String.class)` which gives me the file name.
I am searching for something `Exchange.FILE` which gives me the actual file object. My Ultimate goal is to extract the file in the processor as the routed exchange is an archive file.

Answer (score 12):

Get the file from the body. Camel uses a 'org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile' to store as the file body. But you can use Camel's type converters to get the file in a type you want.

For example you can get the content in different types, such as:

```
String text = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
byte[] bytes = exchange.getIn().getBody(byte[].class);
InputStream is = exchange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class);
```

Comment: If you want the filename use `String filename = exchange.getIn().getBody(GenericFile.class).getFileName();`

Comment: Maybe your message body is null?

Answer (score 3):

For those who have a `from("file:...")` the following works:

```
File in = exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
```